# Plottig data - time plotting

Tags: matlab, time, plot

I want to plot some data in Matlab, but I'm having problems with properly displaying time.

Time is in format:

```
HH:MM:SS.miliseconds
```

So for example: `11:16:41.835`

I read my `.txt` file (tab delimited), and now I need to plot data. All data are the same length, and I reckon there is a problem with the time format. Any advice? `plot(time, data1)` doesn't work either.

Comment: For example I want to show my time in minutes in graph (so 11:16:51.835 would be 0 minutes and so one...end time is 20 minute in my data)

Comment: my .txt file:
http://www.crocko.com/E26E4C5AAAEC47CD968EA63D64EA2022/test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using matlab's built-in datavec, for example:

```
 dvec = datevec('11:21:02.647', 'HH:MM:SS.FFF') 

dvec =   1.0e+003 *
2.0100    0.0010    0.0010    0.0110    0.0210    0.0026
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html)