# Plot time in Matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plottig data - time plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115534/plottig-data-time-plotting)

I have problem with ploting time in MATLAB;

Time is in form: HH:MM:SS.FFF, for example (10:56:43.428)

How to plot this? I tried with "datenum(Time, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF');  and plot, and then datetick;

But this is not OK, when I zoom graph there is no more "time" on x-axis.

Is there any other way to plot time directly, so i can use "zoom" and still seeing time x axis?

---

Second Question: (I would like to start my time from 0 to 20 minutes, so I want my vector 'Time', substract all values with first, so I will get time from 00:00.FFF to end time... How can I do this in Matlab?

Thank a lot for your help, i tried to find help in matlab help but I didn't get any useful helpful.

Comment: You have already asked a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115534/plottig-data-time-plotting). Why not revise it?

Answer (score 0):

From the Matlab documentation on datenum

> Calling datetick sets the TickMode of the specified axis to 'manual'. This means that after zooming, panning or otherwise changing axis limits, you should call datetick again to update the ticks and labels.

So simply call datetick again after you zoom in

Comment: yes but after I do that matlab automatically zoom out..